# Map Array Filter on Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I'm trying to add a value of metafield in XML Feed using omegashoppingfeed.

Using `{% assign test123 = product.meta_fields %}` and after that in the feed i'm using

```
 <product>
              <oeo15>{{ test123 }}</oeo15>
              <id>{{product.id}}</id>
    </product>
```

The result is the following

`<oeo15>map[global:map[%ce%b1%ce%b9%cf%83%ce%b8%ce%b7:Επιταχυνσιόμετρο Καρδιακών Παλμών Παρακολούθηση Ύπνου Βηματόμετρο %ce%bf%ce%b8%cf%8c%ce%bd%ce%b7:Ναι %cf%83%cf%85%ce%bc%ce%b2%ce%b1:Android, iOS %cf%84%cf%8d%cf%80%ce%bf%cf%82:Band %cf%87%cf%81%cf%8e%ce%bc%ce%b1:Μαύρο description_tag:Activity-Tracker-XIAOMI-Mi-Band-4-Black title_tag:Activity Tracker XIAOMI Mi Band 4 Black weight:1.00000000 Αισθητήρες:Επιταχυνσιόμετρο Καρδιακών Παλμών Παρακολούθηση Ύπνου Βηματόμετρο Οθόνη_2nd:Ναι Τύπος_2nd:Band Χρώμα_2nd:Μαύρο] mc-facebook:map[google_product_category:1604] skroutzfeed:map[mpn:XMSH07HM]]</oeo15>`

How can I get the value of the metafield called `mpn?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace as well:

```
product.metafields.<namespace>.mpn
```

The standard way to access product metafields is:

```
product.metafields.<namespace>.<key>
```

or

```
product.metafields.<namespace>['<key>']
```

Example:

```
{% assign instructions = product.metafields.instructions %}
{% assign key = 'Wash' %}
<ul>
  <li>Wash: {{ instructions[key] }}</li>
  <li>Wash: {{ instructions['Wash'] }}</li>
  <li>Wash: {{ instructions.Wash }}</li>
</ul>
```

More [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield)